How do I know when I have sufficiently mastered a right hand speed drill for accordion?
I am self-teaching accordion, principally out of Palmer-Hughes accordion series. The books I am learning from contain selections from CL Hanon's exersises for the right hand. I understand that these speed drills are meant to build up dexeterity, strength, and precision through regular practice, though to be honest I can't say I understand exactly what their goals are on a deeper level than that.
I execute these speed drills as I work through my practice routine, which covers material from the books I don't feel I have 'finished' learning from. However, these speed drills are far trickier to evaluate. The book where these are introduced (Palmer-Hughes vol 2) advises:

From this point on we will have speed drills. They should be practiced daily. These are very famous exercises [...] used [...] to develop speed and technique. Start all speed drills very slowly, then gradually increase speed. Be sure each note is clear and distinct.

That's well and good, but... well... when am I done? With musical pieces in these books, there is often a point where I can say that I recognize what the piece was intended to teach, I have learned it, and I can play the piece fluidly and well. So I move on. But the speed drills can always go faster. Go fast enough, and mistakes are inevitable.
So, as a learner without a teacher to aid me, how do I know when I'm "done," and can stop practicing a given speed drill?

One idea of these sort of exercises is that they are in fact drills. Drills designed to help you play certain things without thinking about what you're playing. Automatically.
When you reach the point where you can say, maybe, the alphabet, or 2x tables, while playing a drill, you know it's embedded in your muscle memory. Not sure what benefit there is in going at breakneck speed, but that won't/cant happen cleanly until that memory point is reached. At which time, you can tidy it up, or play it with a different rhythm, or with different dynamics, proving the point.

You're never 'done' with speed drills. You can get faster and faster, although at some point you'll approach your personal limit where you can't increase the speed any more and still play rhythmically and cleanly. That might take months or years. But even when you're at your limit, you are going to need to regularly play those drills to keep your speed up.
This applies to any instrument.

+1 To paraphrase a jazz teacher I had recently, "you're done when you're dead".

I think it's important to remember that we're playing for fun. I've started playing exercises more since I started on CBA, but in part it's because I enjoy them. I don't really know which ones are the best.
It might be good to try out different exercises before making a real commitment. If you don't know why you're doing them, maybe look around a bit?

As the answers above imply, there's no fixed answer here.  It depends what you're aiming for.  I would just add that it's helpful to record yourself and listen- it's easier to judge your performance when not performing.  And keep in mind that music doesn't have to be fast to be good.
